# Data is gone when sort or searched using Data Table jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I really need your help here. I am new with jQuery DataTable. What I am doing is, I have a url (backend laravel php) that returns a JSON response like so:

```
[
{"kode_pt":1,"nama":"title","SK_path":"\/folder","email_PJ":"\/images","validasi":0},
{"kode_pt":2,"nama":"title","SK_path":"\/folder","email_PJ":"\/images","validasi":0}
]
```

[image: json response]

What I am doing currently is using ajax jquery to GET the data, and add it to the table dynamically. Like this:

```
  var content="";
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{route('get.pt')}}',
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        content+='<tr>'+
          '<td>'+data[i].kode_pt+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+data[i].nama+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+data[i].validasi+'</td>'
          +'<td><button id="accept" data-id='+data[i].kode_pt+' class="btn btn-success">Accept</button><button data-id='+data[i].kode_pt+' class="btn btn-danger">Decline</button><button id="view" data-id='+data[i].kode_pt+' class="btn btn-info">View</button></td>';
      }

  $("#verify-pt-body").html(content);
},
error: function(){
  console.log("Ajax Error - getPT");
}
  });
```

It works. But when I use the sort and search functionality of data table, the data shown onscreen disappears. After browsing, it turns out I cannot apply it to the table like that. I have to use the DataTable's functions to retrieve the json. I need help with that please. I have looked at few documentations but I have failed to get it working. Help would be much appreciated!!

Syntax of data tables I tried but failed:

```
$('#dataTable-verify-pt').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    ajax:{
      url: '//route('get.pt')}}'
    },
    columns:[
      {data: "kode_pt"},
      {data: "nama"},
      {data: "validasi"},

    ]

  });
```

This is the format I'm trying to achieve with DataTable:
[image]